# Color edges of graph w/r/t large induced subgraphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

Can we color the edges of any graph $G$ on $2m-1$ vertices with two colors such that any induced subgraph with at least $m$ edges is non-monochromatic?

If true, this would be sharp as shown by the star $K_{1,2m-1}$.